# I have chemistry as my majors but I recently failed my phd qualifying exam

Tags: phd

I have always been an academically well performing student with good grades but i recently failed my phd qualifying exam and going to get terminal masters with thesis. I have no high paying job prospects like people from engineering background do have after masters. Please advise. Due to the surplus of PhD students from chemistry, industries tend to prefer them for jobs over masters students. I want to reapply to a phd program but do not know what prospects i hold. kindly help

Answer (score 1):

First, this is a good time to review all of your options. Try to find a few that you haven't yet considered and figure out the pros and cons.

But if you really still want to pursue a doctorate, I don't think the door is closed. There are quite a few people in the same position as yourself, though I don't know about how it is in your field.

But, the way to figure out your prospects, really, is to put together all of your qualifications, even including non-obvious ones, and apply to a few programs.

There are a lot of reasons for failing comprehensives/qualifiers. Many of them are incidental to your actual suitability for a degree. But it would be good if you figure out why you failed yours and see if there is some remediation that needs to be done.

One reason is over-confidence. Another, at the other end of the scale, is lack of faith in yourself. There are also technical reasons, of course. Figure it out.

---

Personal note. I've been in the same situation. The faith of one professor in my ability helped me move to a much better situation with a much better advisor. Then: success.